# Clojure Parallel Mapping and Infinite Sequences

Tags: performance, optimization, dictionary, clojure, parallel-processing

Let's say I define the sequence of all natural numbers in the following way:

```
(def naturals (iterate inc 0))
```

I also define a function mapping the naturals to nil that takes a while to compute like so:

```
(defn hard-comp [_] (Thread/sleep 500))
```

Note the computation time to evaulate the following s-expressions as measured by `clojure.core/time`.

`(dorun (map hard-comp (range 30)))  ;`  15010.367496 msecs

`(dorun (pmap hard-comp (range 30))) ;`  537.044554 msecs

`(dorun (map hard-comp (doall (take 30 naturals)))))  ;`  15009.488499 msecs

`(dorun (pmap hard-comp (doall (take 30 naturals)))) ;`  **3004.499013 msecs**

`(doall (take 30 naturals))  ;`  0.385724 msecs

`(range 30)`  ;  0.159374 msecs

`pmap` is ~6 times faster when called with an explicit range than with a section of the naturals.

Since `(= (range 30) (take 30 naturals))` returns true and both objects are of type `clojure.lang.LazySeq`, and clojure evaulates all the arguments to a function before calling the function, how can the above timing details be explained?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that it's due to this:

```
user> (chunked-seq? (seq (range 30)))
true
user> (chunked-seq? (seq (take 30 naturals)))
false
user> (class (next (range 30)))
clojure.lang.ChunkedCons
user> (class (next (take 30 naturals)))
clojure.lang.Cons
```

Try this:

```
user> (defn hard-comp [x] (println x) (Thread/sleep 500))
#'user/hard-comp
user> (time (dorun (pmap hard-comp (range 100))))
```

Note that it jumps 32 items at a time.  That's how many elements are grabbed per chunk for a range.  Chunked seqs pre-evaluate a bunch of items ahead of time to increase performance.  In this case it looks like `pmap` chunkily spawns 32 threads as soon as you try to grab even one element from the range.

You could always stuff your naturals into a vector to get chunking behavior.

```
user> (time (dorun (pmap hard-comp (range 100))))
"Elapsed time: 2004.680192 msecs"
user> (time (dorun (pmap hard-comp (vec (take 100 naturals)))))
"Elapsed time: 2005.887754 msecs"
```

(Note that the time is approximately 4 x 500 ms, 4 being how many chunks of 32 it takes to get to 100.)

On the other hand, you might not want chunking behavior.  32 threads at a time is a lot.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407876/how-do-i-avoid-clojures-chunking-behavior-for-lazy-seqs-that-i-want-to-short-cir) for examples of how to un-chunkify a seq.