# In Clojure, are lazy seqs always chunked?

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, chunking, lazy-sequences

I was under the impression that the lazy seqs were always chunked.

```
=> (take 1 (map #(do (print \.) %) (range)))
(................................0)
```

As expected 32 dots are printed because the lazy seq returned by `range` is chunked into 32 element chunks. However, when instead of `range` I try this with my own function `get-rss-feeds`, the lazy seq is no longer chunked:

```
=> (take 1 (map #(do (print \.) %) (get-rss-feeds r)))
(."http://wholehealthsource.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default")
```

Only one dot is printed, so I guess the lazy-seq returned by `get-rss-feeds` is not chunked. Indeed:

```
=> (chunked-seq? (seq (range)))
true

=> (chunked-seq? (seq (get-rss-feeds r)))
false
```

Here is the source for `get-rss-feeds`:

```
(defn get-rss-feeds
  "returns a lazy seq of urls of all feeds; takes an html-resource from the enlive library"
  [hr]
  (map #(:href (:attrs %))
       (filter #(rss-feed? (:type (:attrs %))) (html/select hr [:link])))
```

So it appears that chunkiness depends on how the lazy seq is produced. I peeked at the source for the function `range` and there are hints of it being implemented in a "chunky" manner. So I'm a bit confused as to how this works. Can someone please clarify?

---

Here's why I need to know.

I have to following code: `(get-rss-entry (get-rss-feeds h-res) url)`

The call to `get-rss-feeds` returns a lazy sequence of URLs of feeds that I need to examine.

The call to `get-rss-entry` looks for a particular entry (whose :link field matches the second argument of get-rss-entry). It examines the lazy sequence returned by `get-rss-feeds`. Evaluating each item requires an http request across the network to fetch a new rss feed. To minimize the number of http requests it's important to examine the sequence one-by-one and stop as soon as there is a match.

Here is the code:

```
(defn get-rss-entry
  [feeds url]
  (ffirst (drop-while empty? (map #(entry-with-url % url) feeds))))
```

`entry-with-url` returns a lazy sequence of matches or an empty sequence if there is no match.

I tested this and it seems to work correctly (evaluating one feed url at a time). But I am worried that somewhere, somehow it will start behaving in a "chunky" way and it will start evaluating 32 feeds at a time. I know there is a way to [avoid chunky behavior as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407876/how-do-i-avoid-clojures-chunking-behavior-for-lazy-seqs-that-i-want-to-short-ci), but it doesn't seem to even be required in this case.

Am I using lazy seq non-idiomatically? Would loop/recur be a better option?

Comment: It appears that a sequence is only "chunked" if you use the various chunk functions in `clojure.core` and/or your sequence implements the `IChunk` and `IChunkedSeq` interfaces. Currently (in 1.4.0), these are undocumented.

Comment: what version of clojure are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the vagueness of Chunking seems unwise as you mention above. Explicitly "un chunking" in cases where you really need it not to be chunked is also wise because then if at some other point your code changes in a way that chunkifies it things wont break. On another note, **if you need actions to be sequential, agents are a great tool** you could send the download functions to an agent then they will be run one at a time and only once regardless of how you evaluate the function. At some point you may want to `pmap` your sequence and then even un-chunking will not work though using an atom will continue to work correctly.

Comment: Could you please expand upon this with a sketch of sample code? Do you mean agents instead of atoms?

Comment: do you mean agent rather than atom here? because functions provided to swap! will be retried

Comment: s/atom/agent/g sorry about that. My fingers betray my brain and press the wrong keys ... fixed.

Answer (score 11):

You are right to be concerned. Your `get-rss-entry` will indeed call `entry-with-url` more than strictly necessary if the `feeds` parameter is a collection that returns chunked seqs. For example if `feeds` is a vector, `map` will operate on whole chunks at a time.

This problem is addressed directly in Fogus' *Joy of Clojure*, with the function `seq1` defined in chapter 12:

```
(defn seq1 [s]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [[x] (seq s)]
      (cons x (seq1 (rest s))))))
```

You could use this right where you know you want the most laziness possible, right before you call `entry-with-url`:

```
(defn get-rss-entry
  [feeds url]
  (ffirst (drop-while empty? (map #(entry-with-url % url) (seq1 feeds)))))
```

Comment: Thanks very much. BTW Just finished the book and it took my Clojure game to the next level. Can't wait for the updated version.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this unchunking call to `seq1` has to be done _at source_. If you're receiving a lazy sequence from `map` over a chunked sequence, for example, you're out of luck - `map` is going to look ahead no matter what you do.

Answer (score 5):

Lazy seqs are **not always chunked** - it depends on how they are produced.

For example, the lazy seq produced by this function is not chunked:

```
(defn integers-from [n]
  (lazy-seq (cons n (do (print \.) (integers-from (inc n))))))

(take 3 (integers-from 3))
=> (..3 .4 5)
```

But many other clojure built-in functions do produce chunked seqs for performance reasons (e.g. [range](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/range))

Comment: It's very important to add that `map` and `filter` both may produce chunked seqs.  Mixing side-effects and laziness is a recipe for subtle bugs.  Transducers help here.

Answer (score 0):

I have discussed this recently in [Can I un-chunk lazy sequences to realize one element at a time?](https://www.tumblr.com/blog/view/holyjak/689730176615120896?source=share) and the conclusion is that if you need to control when items are produced/consumed, you should not use lazy sequences.

For *processing* you can use transducers, where you control when the next item is processed.

For *producing* the elements, the ideal approach is to `reify` `ISeq`. A practical approach is to use `lazy-seq` with a single cons call in it whose rest is a recursive call. But notice that this relies on an implementation detail of lazy-seq.