# Can I process an unrealized lazy-seq step by step

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I have a lazy-seq where each item takes some time to calculate:

```
(defn gen-lazy-seq [size]
  (for [i (range size)]
    (do
      (Thread/sleep 1000)
      (rand-int 10))))
```

Is it possible to evaluate this sequence step by step and print the results. When I try to process it with `for` or `doseq` clojure always realizes the whole lazy-seq before printing anything out:

```
(doseq [item (gen-lazy-seq 10)]
  (println item))

(for [item (gen-lazy-seq 10)]
  (println item))
```

Both expressions will wait for 10 seconds before printing anything out. I have looked at doall and dorun as a solution, but they require that the lazy-seq producing function contain the println. I would like to define a lazy-seq producing function and lazy-seq printing function separately and make them work together item by item.

Motivation for trying to do this:
I have messages coming in over a network, and I want to start processing them before all have been received. At the same time it would be nice to save all messages corresponding to a query in a lazy-seq.

Edit 1:

JohnJ's answer shows how to create a lazy-seq that will be evaluated step by step. I would like to know  how to evaluate any lazy-seq step by step.

I'm confused because running `(chunked-seq? (gen-lazy-seq 10))` on gen-lazy-seq as defined above OR as defined in JohnJ's answer both return false. So then the problem can't be that one creates a chunked sequence and the other doesn't.

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14059959/1026836) answer, a function seq1 which turns a chunked lazy-seq into a non-chunked one is shown. Trying that function still gives the same problem with delayed output. I thought that maybe the delay has to do with the some sort of buffering in the repl, so I tried to also print the time when each item in the seq is realized:

```
(defn seq1 [s]
  (lazy-seq
    (when-let [[x] (seq s)]
      (cons x (seq1 (rest s))))))

(let [start-time (java.lang.System/currentTimeMillis)]
  (doseq [item (seq1 (gen-lazy-seq 10))]
    (let [elapsed-time (- (java.lang.System/currentTimeMillis) start-time)]
      (println "time: " elapsed-time "item: " item))))

; output:
time:  10002 item:  1
time:  10002 item:  8
time:  10003 item:  9
time:  10003 item:  1
time:  10003 item:  7
time:  10003 item:  2
time:  10004 item:  0
time:  10004 item:  3
time:  10004 item:  5
time:  10004 item:  0
```

Doing the same thing with JohnJ's version of gen-lazy-seq works as expected

```
; output:
time:  1002 item:  4
time:  2002 item:  1
time:  3002 item:  6
time:  4002 item:  8
time:  5002 item:  8
time:  6002 item:  4
time:  7002 item:  5
time:  8002 item:  6
time:  9003 item:  1
time:  10003 item:  4
```

Edit 2:

It's not only sequences generated with for which have this problem. This sequence generated with map cannot be processed step by step regardless of seq1 wrapping:

```
(defn gen-lazy-seq [size]
  (map (fn [_] 
         (Thread/sleep 1000)
         (rand-int 10))
       (range 0 size)))
```

But this sequence, also created with map works:

```
(defn gen-lazy-seq [size] 
  (map (fn [_] 
         (Thread/sleep 1000)
         (rand-int 10))
       (repeat size :ignored)))
```

Comment: I also tried `seq1` and didn't manage to get it to work with Clojure 1.5 or with 1.2.1.  It may be that you are up against particularities in the implementation of the `for` macro, which is anything but transparent, and which you cannot simply turn off by wrapping it in your own lazy seq.

Comment: Thanks for testing. It seems reasonable that the problem is due to for. I tried creating a lazy-seq with map and that worked as expected.

Comment: Testing some more, it seems that I have the same problem with sequences generated by map.

Answer (score 4):

Clojure's lazy sequences are often chunked.  You can see the chunking at work in your example if you take large `size`s (it will be helpful to reduce the thread sleep time in this case).  See also [these related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412038/in-clojure-are-lazy-seqs-always-chunked) [SO posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407876/how-do-i-avoid-clojures-chunking-behavior-for-lazy-seqs-that-i-want-to-short-ci).

Though `for` seems to be chunked, the following is not and works as desired:

```
(defn gen-lazy-seq [size]
  (take size (repeatedly #(do (Thread/sleep 1000)
                              (rand-int 10)))))

(doseq [item (gen-lazy-seq 10)]
  (println item))
```

"I have messages coming in over a network, and I want to start processing them before all have been received." Chunked or no, this should actually be the case if you process them lazily.