# a version of `sequence` that doesn't do chunking

Tags: clojure

I'd like to have a version of `sequence` that doesn't do the chunking of 32 elements. Currently, this code will output

```clj
(def peek #(doto % (print " ")))
(def pause #(do (Thread/sleep 10)
                %))

(take 2 (->> (range 100)
             (sequence (comp (map peek)
                             (map pause)
                             (map inc)))))

;; prints 0 1 2 3 4 <..etc..> 32
;; => (0, 1)
```

I'd like a version of it so that it only iterates through the elements that it needs

```clj
(take 2 (->> (range 100)
             (iter-sequence  (comp (map peek)
                             (map pause)
                             (map inc)))))

;; prints 0 1
;; => (0, 1)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I'd guessing it has something to do `iterate` but I'd like to be able to use transducers on it as well.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12412038/in-clojure-are-lazy-seqs-always-chunked – Chousers response in particular.

Comment: @cfrick - so that's the point. I don't want to do that.

Comment: @stefan. this doesn't work because it still generates a seq. I'd like it to generate an iterator (as sequence does) but a non chunking version.

Comment: @cfrick if you replace `take 2` with `first`, it prints 32 elements so the culprit is definitely sequence.

Comment: @zcaudate Yes you are right - my testing was flawed. `sequence` code actually has the chunkedIterator in plain sight

Comment: @cfrick. sweet. I got it working - see answer.

Answer (score 3):

I had to change a couple of things to get it working. The first is to cut and paste `sequence` code and replace `clojure.lang.RT/chunkIteratorSeq` with an alternative version of [clojure.lang.IteratorSeq](https://www.codota.com/web/assistant/code/rs/5c66afd81095a50001da5666#L55) that has exposed public constructor methods.

The reason being is that the `clojure.lang.IteratorSeq/create` has a check to `iter.next()` on L27 which will block if the source is blocking.

```clj
(defn seqiter
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([coll] coll)
  ([xform coll]
   (IteratorSeq.
    (TransformerIterator/create xform (clojure.lang.RT/iter coll))))
  ([xform coll & colls]
   (IteratorSeq.
    (TransformerIterator/createMulti
     xform
     (map #(clojure.lang.RT/iter %) (cons coll colls))))))
```

Comment: the source is here: https://gist.github.com/zcaudate/269d8750b6316166f14be15bfb8aa500#file-iteratorseq-java-L48

Comment: also, https://github.com/cgrand/xforms/blob/master/src/net/cgrand/xforms.cljc#L555 does the same thing.