# laziness does not work as expected

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, chunking

```
(defn seq-trial
  []
  (map #(do (println "hello " %) (inc %)) (range 10)))

(take 3 (seq-trial))
```

The code snippt above when evaluated prints out the following -

(hello  0
hello  1
hello  2
hello  3
hello  4
hello  5
hello  6
hello  7
hello  8
hello  9
1 2 3)

Because map returns a lazy sequence I expected this to print only -

(hello 0
hello 1
hello 2
1 2 3)

Why is the entire list evaluated here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of a performance optimization called chunking. Essentially the sequence is realised in groups of *n* items called chunks. This means you need to take care with any side effects in your mapping function. The end result is correct tho, you still get a sequence of the correct length returned

The default chunk size is 32, so if you increase your range to a value larger than that you will understand what's going on a bit better:

```
user> (defn seq-trial
  []
  (map #(do (println "hello " %) (inc %)) (range 100)))

user> (take 3 (seq-trial))
hello  0 ; 32 item 'chunk' realized...
hello  1

...

hello  30
hello  31
(1 2 3)  ; the expected returned value
```

If you need to avoid chunking there are [options available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407876/how-do-i-avoid-clojures-chunking-behavior-for-lazy-seqs-that-i-want-to-short-ci)

Comment: Side effects and lazy evaluation don't mix.