# Consume http requests lazy

Tags: http, clojure, lazy-evaluation, side-effects

I'm trying to enrich data and the interface I have available for this is a web form.
Due to the very poorly quality of the data on the remote end, I run through a chain of different searches until I get a match. Sometimes I get a hit on the first request sometimes I don't find anything even though I tried 5 different searches.

I thought I could use Clojures laziness to short circuit the searches on the first match but apparently due to side effects all 5 different searches are requested every time.

Here is a very simple reproduction of my problem:

```
(ns lazy-web-lookup.core
  (:require [clj-http.client :as http]))

(defn found?
  "Determines if the search was successful"
  [result]
  (= (:found result) "yes"))

(first (filter #(found? %) (map #(hash-map :no %
                                           :found (:body (http/get "http://localhost/random"))) [1 2 3 4 5])))
```

`http://localhost/random` randomly returns the string "yes" or "no".

Is there anyway I can tweak the above to do what I want or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247045/how-are-lazy-sequences-implemented-in-clojure

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407876/how-do-i-avoid-clojures-chunking-behavior-for-lazy-seqs-that-i-want-to-short-ci

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually **only *chunked* seqs are realized in batches** of (normally<sup>1</sup>) 32 elements. Non-chunked seqs are realized one at a time. Functions like `map` and `filter` preserve the chunked / unchunked "mode" of their seq arguments.

You may thus be able to utilize regular Clojure sequence functions without compromising any amount of laziness if you make sure that you're passing a non-chunked seq to them. There are two possible approaches here, the second one of which is probably more applicable to your case:

1. Produce your seq without regard to whether it's going to be chunked or not; then, if it happens to be chunked, wrap it in an "unchunking seq":

   ```
   (defn unchunk [xs]
     (lazy-seq
       (if-let [xs (seq xs)]
         (cons (first xs) (unchunk (rest xs))))))

   user=> (->> (range 40) (unchunk) (map #(println "THIS IS" %)) first)
   THIS IS 0

   user=> (->> (range 40) (map #(println "THIS IS" %)) first)
   THIS IS 0
   THIS IS 1
   THIS IS 2
   ...
   ```

   **To use this approach with the example in the question text, you'd have to unchunk the seq over the vector `[1 2 3 4 5]`.**
2. Produce your initial seq (the innermost one in your transformation pipeline) in some way which does not happen to chunk the output. This may involve writing your own producers explicitly:

   ```
   (defn my-seq-producer [& args]
     (lazy-seq
       (if ...
         (cons (foo) (my-seq-producer ...))))
   ```

   The key thing to note here is that you're wrapping a `cons` call in a conditional inside `lazy-seq`. If the test in the conditional is not satisfied, the conditional will produce `nil` and the lazy seq will turn out to be empty upon being realized; otherwise `(foo)` will be produced as the first element of the output, followed by come "rest" part of the sequence, without any chunking.

   **In particular, if you write your own producer of a lazy seq of items fetched over HTTP, you will be able to transform it using the core sequence functions while preserving full laziness.**

The simplest way to tell which seq is chunked and which is not is to use the `chunked-seq?` function, although there are two caveats:

1. You should probably use `chunked-seq?` on the result of calling `seq` on whichever seq you're interested in, rather than the original seq itself. This is because your seq might be a chunked-seq-producing thunk wrapped in a `LazySeq` object. In fact, this is the case with `range`.

   ```
   (chunked-seq? (range 40))
   ;= false

   (chunked-seq? (seq (range 40)))
   ;= true
   ```
2. A seq may be partially chunked; for example you might `cons` something onto the front of a chunked seq, thereby producing a seq which is not chunked, but which nevertheless has a chunked "rest". Explicit unchunking deals with this happily, since it doesn't really check whether the underlying seq is chunked or not.

---

<sup>1</sup> Consider a seq over a vector whose tail is less than 32 elements long.

Comment: This unchunking seems pretty awesome :)
Personally I like the structure of the map filter better than the loop recur... do you have comment on comparing those two solutions?

Comment: For transforming sequences of data, I'd pretty much always go with sequence library functions first and only use loop/recur if it felt particularly clear or if I could measure a significant performance benefit. Loop/recur used to be useful for finishing certain types of transformations early, but now that `reduce` can be short-circuited (see `(doc reduced)` in Clojure >= 1.5), this is less often the case. The declarative feel of seq transforms is one reason; also, loop/recur is closed, while seq transforms are open: you can stack more on top of a pipeline without modifying it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answer, lazy sequences are realized in batch mode where batch size is 32, for your specific problem you can use plain old recursion:

```
(loop [i [1 2 3 4 5]]
  (when (seq i)
    (let [body (-> (http/get "http://localhost/random")
                   :body)]
      (if (= body "yes")
        body
        (recur (rest i))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

For efficiency reasons, lazy sequences are evaluated 32 elements at a time.  Try this:

```
> (defn f [i] (= i 2))
#'sandbox10079/f
> (defn g [i] (println "THIS IS" i) i))
#'sandbox10079/g
> (defn h [x] (first (filter f (map g x))))
#'sandbox10079/h
> (h (range 40))
THIS IS 0
THIS IS 1
THIS IS 2
THIS IS 3
THIS IS 4
THIS IS 5
  ...
THIS IS 28
THIS IS 29
THIS IS 30
THIS IS 31
2
>
```